# How to use PowerShell to get information about a Staging Windows Azure WebSite slot?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, powershell-cmdlet

I'm using the PowerShell CmdLets to automate most tasks against Windows Azure Cloud Services and Windows Azure Web Sites.

For Cloud Services, I can use the `Get-AzureDeployment` CmdLet. However, the similar `Get-AzureWebSiteDeployment` CmdLet requires Git to be installed before it can run and does not seem to be designed for the same task.

As far as I can see, the `Get-AzureWebSite` CmdLet only ever retrieves the "Production" slot of a Windows Azure Web Site.

How is it possible to get programmatic access to the corresponding "Staging" slot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on some PowerShell cmdlets to support website slots. We are very close to releasing it. Keep an eye on this repo on github. https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools

Comment: All links dead. Not the solution anymore

Answer (score 0):

Current date update (Jul 19 2015): 
According to Azure Docs [Web Sites Staging Slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) there are new CMDLets that support querying Slots:

```
Show-AzureWebsite -Name webappslotstest -Slot staging
```

And some others cmdlets extended with -Slot attribute (Create New Website, Remove, Switch Slots).